# convert uppercase letter to lowercase using php

Tags: php

```
  <?php

  $filename = "your htpasswd file path goes here";  // your htpasswd file name - complete       unix path - or relative to this script

 $host=“host”;     
 $dbuser=“usert”;                 
 $dbpswd=“pass";           
 $mysqldb="db_name";            
 $table="passwd_table";       

  mysql_connect("$host", "$dbuser", "$dbpswd");
  mysql_select_db ("$mysqldb");
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM $table");
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  $user = $row['name'];
  $pass = $row['name'];
  $encrypted = crypt($pass);
  $record .= "$user:$encrypted\r\n";
  }
 file_put_contents($filename,$record);
 ?>
```

I am using this php to write a file for htpassword , some of my username/password has uppercase letters , i want to convert it to lowercase then encrypt password and write user/pass to file

Comment: Going with the question title, use `strtolower()`

Comment: And oooooooooooops, you want to change the case of the passwords and than encrypt? Easing up for the hackers?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks research efforts

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php
Also, try to find answers im manuals on the internet, php.net is a good place to start

Comment: Everything is not available for public use and accessible for hackers , Thanks but is there any proper way to convert fetched data to lowercase then encrypt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
$lowercase=strtolower('Your input')
```

**solution**

```
  mysql_connect("$host", "$dbuser", "$dbpswd");
  mysql_select_db ("$mysqldb");
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT name,pass FROM $table");
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  $user = strtolower($row['name']);
  $pass = strtolower($row['pass']);
  $encrypted = crypt($pass);
  $record .= "$user:$encrypted\r\n";
  }
```

Comment: How can i give my sql inout to it

Answer (score 3):

Use *[strtolower](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php)* function

> Returns string with all alphabetic characters converted to lowercase.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
echo strtolower("Hello WORLD.");
?>
```

OUTPUT : hello world.

Try this

Answer (score 0):

I would add that better if to use multibyte functions if you are not 100% sure there will be only standard characters.

For example:

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

...

$user = mb_strtolower($row['name']);
$pass = mb_strtolower($row['pass']);
```